# git rebase creating local-remote disagreement

Tags: git, github

My repo is on GitHub. I was working on `mybranch` that came off `master` a while ago, and both had new commits

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b mybranch
...
git add ...
git commit
git push origin mybranch

====>

[master] -------commit0--
[mybranch]   \--commit1--
```

At this point I pushed `commit1` onto GitHub.

I wanted to check if `commit1` still works under the new `master`, so I did `rebase` (`commit0` and `commit1` have no conflict). To my understanding, it now looks like:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout master
git rebase origin/master
git checkout mybranch
git rebase origin/master

======>

[master] -------commit0--------------
[mybranch]               \--commit1--
```

Everything works fine, and I made new progress `commit2`.

```
git checkout mybranch
...
git add ...
git commit
git push origin mybranch

=====>

[master] -------commit0--------------------------
[mybranch]               \--commit1-----commit2--
```

I pushed changes to GitHub and was ready for pull-request. However, I see now on GitHub that I have 3 commits:

```
new to old:
- commit2
- commit0
- commit1
```

This is annoying, because `commit0` is already part of master, and it has nothing to do with `mybranch`. The file change from `commit0` is also showing up in my pull request, which is undesirable. So I did the *"natural"* thing: `revert commit0` in `mybranch`.

```
git checkout mybranch
git revert [commit0]
git push origin mybranch
```

Now the pull request looks better: it only has changes from `commit1` and `commit2`.

However, on my local repo, since I `revert`ed `commit0`, I have don't have its content on `mybranch`. `git log` shows:

```
new to old:
- revertcommit0 (HEAD -> mybranch)
- commit2
- commit1
- commit0 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
...
```

At this point:

- What should I do to solve this discrepancy? I'd like to have the newest `master` commits on `mybranch`, AND only push relevant changes to `mybranch`. Is this asking for too much?
- What should I have done differently to avoid this? Would `merge` perhaps be better practice?

Comment: It would be possible to help if you let us know via commands how you ended up in that situation. Or if you are using some git client , then let add that information.

Comment: Rebase does not *change* any commits. Rebase *copies* them, to new and improved ones. The old ones are still there. You're using the new ones instead of the old ones. You've told the *other* Git to use the old ones, and have not yet sent it the new ones. Later, you tell your Git to use *both* the old ones (obtained from their Git) and the new ones. Read up on the graph structure of commits: http://think-like-a-git.net/